# Missing rule for this simple identity?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a simple rule I am missing to help prove the identity below? Of course I can find the common denominator, do multiplication, summarize, apply trigonometric product-to-sum identities, and then undo the previous steps.

Besides the trigonometric identities, is there an rule or identity I am missing?

$$-\frac{\sin(a-n\pi)}{c-d}-\frac{\sin(a+n\pi)}{c+d}  = -\frac{\sin(a)\cos(n\pi)}{c-d}-\frac{\sin(a)\cos(n\pi)}{c+d}, \quad n\in \mathbb N,\quad c^2-d^2\neq0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows immediately from $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$. Here, since $\beta=n\pi$, $\sin(\beta)=0$.

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot!